# Azure DevOps - Releases Task is automatically set to "Scoped to resource group ''"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

In our `Azure Active Directory` we have set up an `App Registration` for our service connection. The App Registration has Role `Contributor` for two different Resource Groups that in turn exists in two different subscriptions.

When the service connection is used it is automatically scoped to one resource group in one subscription anyway and this can't be changed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at Azure DevOps - Service connections we can see that even though the app has access to both subscriptions and resource groups it is in our case already mapped to a specific subscription and resource group.

[image]

Add a new service connection, choose Azure Resource Manager, Service Principal (automatic) and set it up against the other subscription or set up a new Management Group.